# Яндекс.Метрика затормаживает загрузку сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, битрикс, pagespeed-insights

Если прогнать сайт через https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/, то наблюдается интересная штука.

В разделе влияние стороннего кода видно, что сторонний код Яндекс.Метрики блокирует основной поток на 16 607 мс, что, согласитесь, достаточно много! Для сравнения GoogleAnalytics - всего 74 мс.

А в разделе время выполнения кода JS указано, что из 22,6 секунд выполнения кода 21 075 мс занимает выполнение кода

```
/metrika/tag.js(mc.yandex.ru) т.е. опять Яндекс.Метрика.
```

Что посоветуете делать? Отказываться от Яндекс.Метрики? Или есть какое-то другое решение.

Comment: А почему исключаете вариант посмотреть в сторону оптимизации подключения скриптов? Подключаете ли этот скрипт асинхронно? Где подключаете в шапке или в подвале?

Comment: Скрипт подключается в подвале, одна из последних строк. Но не асинхронно - сейчас попробую подключить асинхронно.

Comment: По итогу, что было сделано. 1.По совету форума Я.Метрики был отключен Вебвизор 2.0. 2. Добавлен тег `async` при подключении javascript. 
Из PageSpeed упоминание Я.Метрики исчезло!

Comment: Как вариант, можно еще обернуть вызов функции инициализации метрики или весь код скрипта в `setTimeout` с отсрочкой от 5 секунд.

Comment: @GHosT это решение зааффектит метрики Яндес.Метрики

Comment: @AlexanderMatveev , безусловно, но по крайней мере Google перестал ругаться на этот шлак. Если метрика важнее, то не стоит руководствоваться PageSpeed для оптимизации страниц — у Яндекса есть свои инструменты.